# Add custom field in rss category feeds magento

Tags: magento-1.7, rss

I want to add custom field to the description field in category feeds.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry that this is not a complete answer but I think in addition to extending `Mage_Rss_Block_Catalog_Category` as mentioned by Marius you will also need to deal with extending `Zend_Feed_Rss`.

What happens with `Zend_Feed_Rss` is that it will only add nodes that it knows about so you will not be able to add your custom node as desired. One thing to think about would be use an currently existing node like `comment`, check the function `_mapFeedEntries` for valid nodes.

Comment: You are right. Zend_Feed_Rss ignores custom tags. Maybe there is a reason for this. I'm not very familiar with the RSS structure, but maybe you should not put custom tags in RSS feeds. I deleted my answer... Oh yeah, and +1 for spotting this.